# Question about my usb wirless network adapter

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers

I have a D-Link DWA-140 USB network adapter as my network card is knackered so I removed it.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and for some reason my Internet is awfully slow when surfing, downloading Ubuntu updates and downloading software in the software center but torrents download fast as anything, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

PC Specs:

```
- 2.5ghz core2quad Q8600 or Q8300 (don't remember which it is)
- 4GB RAM
- Nvidia GTX 560TI
```

---

hey bruno thanks for the help your are offering and im sorry for posting this as an answer again but honestly there is no add comment link on my screen anywhere all i see is share  edit and feedback was this helpful yess or no. so rather than destroy this question post anymore im just going to give up with linux lol.

P.S there are no torrents running and the internet is still slow for browsing etc

ummmmm the only place i can see add comment is under my own answer which is strange as hell

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installed nvidia driver, `nouveau` can be replaced by a proprietary driver in System Settings> Additional Drivers. As for internet - connect to an Ethernet connection and test speed with speedtest.net and do the same with no Ethernet.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I checked my wireless speed and its 5mbits/s and under. my wired speed is 50mbits/s. as i stated before my speeds are so slow when surfing/downloading updates/downloading from software center (fluctuating between 6kb/s and 200kb/s where as torrents zoom at 3.5mb/s (bytes not bits just incase you thought i may have them confused lol)

Comment: Consider the fact that WiFi proximity/speeds and your adapter speeds might slow down browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have your torrent client configured to take up all your connection, you need to reduce the number of simultaneous downloads or reduce the number of connections per download.

If you are using Transition (the default in 12.04) the options you are looking for are:

#### Maximum Active Downloads

[image]
<sub>This is the number of simultaneous files you are downloading</sub>

#### Maximum peers overall

[image]
<sub>Maximum number of connections to other users available to all your downloading files</sub>

A good idea is to start small, reduce all to 10% of what you have at the moment and increase them every 5 minutes and check if the web browser speed is acceptable.